# Socket IO net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, sockets, angular, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to implement socket.io into my application which is hosted at Azurewebsites. `webapp`

Here is the server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("Socket connected :"+socket.id);
 socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

And Here is the client side socket. index.html

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script>
        var socket = io('http://localhost:3001');
        console.log("scoekt connect",socket)
      socket.on('connect', function(){ console.log('connected to socket'); });
      socket.on('error', function(e){ console.log('error' + e); });

    socket.on( 'news', function( data ){
    console.log("socket data",data);

    });</script>
```

I am getting the below error
[image]

I am not really sure whats is going wrong. Here is the structure of file-ing system

```
ROOT
app/
index.html
server.js
web.config
```

PS: this is an Angular2 application

PS: I have checked all the suggested question based on this error but none solved my issue, thus i am posting this question.

Comment: You say: "*my application which is hosted at Azurewebsites*", but your client side is connecting with `localhost`.

Comment: My client and server, both are hosted at same website! So I am really sure it this right? Because when tried wit two different sites i.e server side different and client side diff, it asks me provide "Allow-cross-origin-header" in the url at `var socket = io(<url>);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my experience, Azure Web App doesn't bind `loaclhost` or `127.0.0.1` to your website, and only ports 80 and 443 are public-facing. This maps to a specific port for your app to listen to, retrievable via `process.env.PORT`. So you'd need to replace

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3001');
```

with

```
var socket = io('http://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net');
```

And if your server side and client side in the different domain, you'd also need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on the server side. In Azure, we can enable it with the Azure portal.

- In a browser, go to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/), and navigate to your App Service.
- Click **CORS** in the **API** menu.
- Enter each URL in the empty **Allowed Origins** text box. A new text box is created. As an alternative, you can enter an asterisk (*) to specify that all origin domains are accepted.
- Click **Save**.

[image]

Socket.IO uses WebSockets, which are not enabled by default on Azure. You can also enable WebSocket support using the Azure Portal. Please see the steps below.

- In the Azure portal, click **Application settings** in the **SETTINGS** menu.
- Under **Web Sockets** click **On**
- Click **Save**.

[image]

For more info, please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!. May I know why does sometimes angular doesn't load modules indicated in the script to load. It say 404 not found... even if it there.

Comment: You can enable `Always On` to keep the app loaded all the time on Azure. More details, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure.

Comment: `(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<socketsite>.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LeN6Skj. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://<clientsite>.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access.` even if adding * at CORS

Comment: Have you enabled CORS in your server side (socketsite)?

Comment: Yeap! On both sites! and Web sockets too!

Comment: `var socket = io('<url>', {transports: ['websocket']})`; Could you please have a try `websocket` transport in your clent side?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!