# Deploying node.js + socket.io backend/server on azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I have the following error when running my server on web service in `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\logging-errors.txt`:

```
Mon Mar 13 2017 21:36:58 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
TypeError: server.listeners is not a function
    at Server.attach (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:424:26)
    at Function.attach (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\engine.io.js:124:10)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:240:21)
    at new Server (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:52:17)
    at Server (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:40:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:1:92)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

This is my server side code(the beginning of it):

```
var io = require('socket.io')(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var AI = require('./AI');
var gamelogic = require('./gamelogic');
var shortid = require('shortid');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit("Testing");
```

And at the client side(C#, with a module for socket.io):

```
socket.On ("Testing", Test);

public void Test(SocketIOEvent e)
{
    Debug.Log ("Server is running and communicating");

}
```

This is my connection string to the server:

```
ws://MyAppname.azurewebsites.net:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
```

The game will be played on android phone, I made the game with unity game engine.

When I am running the server locally, it runs perfectly! Multiple instances connect to the server and join rooms, ai is playing, scores is updating etc. But I can't let it communicate/run it at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following will help.

1) In Azure Web Apps, only ports 80 and 443 are public-facing. So your connection string should look something like:

```
ws://MyAppname.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
```

2) Socket.IO uses WebSockets, which are not enabled by default on Azure. To enable web sockets, please follow the steps at [my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053499/socket-io-neterr-connection-refused/42062626#42062626).

3) Replace the line: `var io = require('socket.io')(process.env.PORT || 3000);` with the following lines of the code.

```
var server = require('http').createServer((req, res) => res.end());
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: Yes!! , It is now working, thank you very much Aaron for your help!