# socket.io + azure app services 503 error even though websockets is ENABLED

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to set up socket.io with my Node.js server on Azure app services. It works perfectly fine in my local server. However, I can't seem to get it to work on Azure.

I have enabled web sockets in my Azure App Services -> configuration -> general settings. However, this does not work.

I have followed instructions in this stackoverflow post: [Socket IO net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053499/socket-io-neterr-connection-refused/42062626#42062626) but it hasn't worked for me.

My server side code:

```
...
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app: Application = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
...
io.of("/chat").on("connection", async function(socket: any) {
  console.log('hi')
});
...
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port} `));
```

My CORS settings have also been set up appropriately, HTTP requests to my server work fine, as well as requests that require a credentials.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT (MORE INFO):

I am using in-house authentication. Because of this, I need to set the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to TRUE. My express app was setting this to true via the cors npm module, however no matter what I did I could not get HTTP requests to work when doing authentication requests.

I was able to solve this by doing:

```
az resource update --name web --resource-group <myResourceGroupName> --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type config --parent sites/<site-name> --set properties.cors.supportCredentials=“true” --api-version 2015-06-01
```

which i found here: (https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api)

This allowed HTTP requests with credentials to work, as well as any other HTTP requests. It is important to note that in my Azure settings, all my CORS settings are still **blank** in order to allow my express app to handle CORS.

Not sure if this is related...

EDIT2:

when I try to connect from my client with

```
    const socketIo = io(socketUrl + "/chat", {
      // transports: ["websocket"]
      upgrade: false,
    })
```

everything works fine. But if i uncomment `transports: ["websocket"]`, connection will fail. It's got to have something to do with the websocket settings in Azure

Comment: are you listening on the app service name: `var socket = io('http://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net');`?

Comment: Please try disabling IIS WebSockets support module (iiswsock.dll) since it isn’t needed by node.js. See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ (Assuming that the app has been deployed to a Windows WebApp)

Comment: also, this might be useful: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19578

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. GauraKumar, it has been deployed to a Linux Web App. It's running Node 12.
4c7436b41, I have tried connecting with both 'http://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net' as well as my own custom domain. nothing is working :(

Comment: Thanks for the link 4c74356b41. I tried their solution of handling CORS completely within my express app, but that also doesn't work. Another solution was to use a windows-based environment in Azure app services, but I can't select that option since it's not supported for Node. Unless I run a docker container which I currently don't want to do

Comment: 4c74356b41, when you asked me if i was listening on the app service name `var socket = io('http://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net');`, you were referring to client, correct?

Comment: Did you try setting perMessageDeflate to false as mentioned here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq.md#language-support

Comment: I did, still no luck :(

Comment: added some more info to my post...

Comment: Are you running your node.js app as a cluster/on multiple threads?

Comment: Also have a look at this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd2edff3-b176-4084-8c81-dd289914ba0b

Comment: Thanks for sharing that rezadru. I am not running my app as a cluster. Also, i tried everything in the thread, perMessageDeflate, AlwaysOn, but no success:(

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to provide a minimal working example (server and a client page) it would simplify things.

Here are a couple things to check:

- Disable `perMessageDeflate` in your server-side Node.js code

for example like this:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{
   perMessageDeflate :false
});
```

- Azure Web Apps only listens on ports 80 & 443 which is a common issue

It doesn't look like a case here, but it happens so often, so I will leave it here to help others. According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq):

> **Q: Can I expose more than one port on my custom container image?**
>
> A: We don't support exposing more than one port.
> So, if this is a case - change the port to either of them and your app will work fine.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

So I made a barebones example to test the socket connection... and it worked.

Then, I tried my app again.. and it worked. Dunno what happened but everything is working now...